# How to add specific string if it is not exists in current file?

Tags: vimscript, text-generation

I want to add this string "`declare(strict_types=1);`" after `<?php` when I save or open a file.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
```

If the file already contains `declare(strict_types=1);` don't do anything.

Maybe there is a plugin or something?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
function! AddPHPStrictTypes()
    " Save the cursor position
    let cursor_save = getpos('.')

    " Go to the begining of the file
    call cursor(1, 1)

    " Get the line containing "<?php"
    let phpLine = search('<?php')

    " If the declaration isn't in the buffer and there is one line containing "<?php"
    if search('<?php\ndeclare(strict_types=1);') == 0 && phpLine != 0
        " Add the declaration after the line
        call append(phpLine, "declare(strict_types=1);")
    endif

    " Restore cursor position
    call setpos('.', cursor_save)
endfunction


autocmd! BufReadPost *php call AddPHPStrictTypes()
```

We declare a function which searches for the declaration. If the declaration is not found it search for the line containing `<?php` and add the declaration after it.

Then we use an autocommand to execute the function each time you open a new php file.

To understand the function better you may want to read

- [`:h getpos()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getpos%28%29)
- [`:h setpos()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#setpos%28%29)
- [`:h cursor()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#cursor%28%29)
- [`:h search()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#search%28%29)
- [`:h append()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#append%28%29)

And to change the autocommand:

- [`:h :autocmd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#%3aautocmd)
- [`:h autocmd-events`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd-events)

Comment: use `append()`, instead of putting, be sure to set the cursor to the beginning of the file before searching and restore the position later

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thanks for your comment, I updated my answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, It works perfectly & I learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I love the accepted solution. But for anyone else who wants to do this quickly, but not always automatically, here is another solution:

```
iabbrev dst declare(strict_types=1);
```

With this, in insert mode, move the cursor where you want, then type `dst`, then hit the space bar, and it will auto-complete it.

If you are working in legacy code environments, it's nice because you can't always add strict types on every file you touch in some cases.